# Mixed content issue even after deleting that content

Tags: wordpress, ssl, elementor, mixed-content

My coding knowledge is super basic but Hostinger's support sent me to this platform to hopefully find a solution.

Situation: I have successfully installed the SSL certificate but I keep losing the padlock because of mixed content. I checked Whynopadlock for the issues, it gave me two images as 'soft failures'. I deleted those from my Wordpress library. I've installed Really Simple SSL, Force SSL and tried Search & Replace. I've changed the url in Elementor but I keep getting these errors.

Please, can someone help me, with some clear info as my coding knowledge is limited to making some minor changes in css.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: What is your URL?

Comment: The URL for the website is https://cortijolamorera.com

Answer (score 0):

In your homepage, there are 3 images that are still loading under http instead of https. These images are:

- http://cortijolamorera-com.preview-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/ligature-symbols_2-11-0_quote_225_13_bdc3c7_none.png
- http://cortijolamorera-com.preview-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Algemeen7-scaled.jpeg
- http://cortijolamorera-com.preview-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/evie-shaffer-728405-unsplash-edited.jpg

All these images appear to load from lazysizes.js. The easiest way would be to delete these photos from the media library and upload them again. Otherwise, you can either check your setting in the lazysizes plugin or search and replace the urls from within the database.

Comment: Hi there, 
Thank you so much for your reply! 

The weird thing is that I've deleted those images already (except the second one). I wasn't using the others so I just deleted them from the library. I've also deactivated the lazyloading, to be safe. I've tried a search & replace plugin earlier but that didn't work either and I don't feel comfortable enough to change URLs in the database as I've never done that before.